# Facebook leaderboard

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, leaderboard

I was wondering whether anyone had any useful guides for implementing Facebook scores in an Android game. I am currently building a profile in-game but there are lots of features in the Facebook SDK and Graph API that I don't know how to use.

Is anyone familiar with posting scores and retrieving leaderboards of your Facebook friends?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the API? As stated, its overly broad will likely get closed.

Comment: Well in the new Sdk what request can i do to post a score of a individual user for my game and what request can i do to receive the highscores for all the friends of the player for my game so i can show them in the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your own leaderboard - store the scores in your database, calculate rank, etc and use standard open graph actions to publish to users walls.

Alternatively, you can use Facebooks [scores API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/) which handles a lot of this for you, however it does have its limitations. You can also use the [Achievements API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) which allows you to post stream stories to the users timeline like 'Joe just unlocked the Star Badge'.

Finally, you could use a third party tool such as [Leaderboarded](http://www.leaderboarded.com/home/product/data/), although I'm not sure how relevant this is to your game.

As for useful guide - I've found it better/more relevant to provide friend leaderboards rather than global leaderboards, as these are often more interesting to the user.

Comment: thanks! I will look into the Score Api first seems to provide what i need!