# SwarmConnect Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, leaderboard

Hello I am using the SwarmConnect Social feutures for my Game to have a leaderboard.

Besides that i don't know yet how to costumize...their Documentation is very poor...

I have also trouble to connect to Swarm via the Facebook log in...maybe the twitter and google logins dont work as well who knows...

But the normal login works fine i can see in my admin panel the score i have submitted.

What does go wrong there?

I enteter my login details and then there is just a blank frame that i can close and still am not logged in!!!

Edit: I would also appreciate that at least if you know one, to tell me a better solution for a Lederboard in my game that is free and supports at least facebook login, Google plus and or twitter

Comment: What trouble are you having with the facebook login?

Comment: as i said...i enter my login data click confrim an then there is just a blank frame with a close button...when i close it im just back to the log in and the edittexts are empty...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You try openkit:
https://github.com/OpenKit/openkit-android - there You have some examples and better documentation.
Or You can Try use facebook score Api as some other SO user suggests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692956/1257522

Comment: the facebook score api is not good because you can only interact with friends and so I cant have global Leaderboards.

Comment: at least you tried to show another way and  I will give you the bounty for free :)